# Is there a way to install Microsoft Store-exclusive apps without Store?

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop

Unlike apps I can download online and install, I can't figure out how to install apps that are only availabe for download via Ms-Store app, without first installing Ms-Store.

I ask this because I am planning to install preconfigured Windows 10 lite build which comes without Ms Store app and most of the built-in Windows bundle apps, to reduce total size and improve performance.

Any tips?

Answer (score 8):

1. Go to https://apps.microsoft.com/store/apps
2. Search for your App
3. Copy the ID from the URL, for example: `9WZDNCRFJ3TJ`
4. run the following command `winget install 9WZDNCRFJ3TJ -s msstore`

If you do not have winget here are some instructions how to install:
https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli

Answer (score 4):

check this app out it can download and install ms store app with a few clicks no fluff just select the app and vola its installed!
https://github.com/m-jishnu/alt-app-installer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

This is what I tried and worked out for me:

1. go to MS Store and copy the link of the app you want to install https://apps.microsoft.com/store/apps
2. Copy the link of the app and paste in this website, search in RP mode https://store.rg-adguard.net
3. In the result, find the .appx file of the app you need and right click and save as, your browser might detect it as a harmful app, you can ignore and keep the file
4. Make sure you also download all the dependencies and save them as well
5. Once you download all the dependencies and the application, start by installing dependencies first, and then the main app
6. To install, go to the downloads location, right click on each and click Install
7. Optional: you can also install via powershell `Add-AppxPackage -Path "<PATH>".appx`

Comment: please add instructions how to install via powershell?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these basic steps:

1. Find and download the required appx package (bundled store apps). There are a few ways to do this, the steps [here](http://woshub.com/how-to-download-appx-installation-file-for-any-windows-store-app/#:%7E:text=There%20are%20two%20ways%20to,Links%20for%20Microsoft%20Store%20Apps) are pretty straightforward
2. Install the appx packages:

   - just double-click the .appx file (this might use the store to install though)
   - via powershell: `Add-AppxPackage c:\path\to\app.appx`.

The success here depends on how the Store was removed from your build and which app you want to install. Just downloading the installation package is often not enough unless the vendor has approved the app for offline installation. Each store app may require a license file as well.

If these steps don't work for your specific app, the MS Store app itself can also be installed the same way