# Has anyone found a way to bypass Windows store that can allow you to download the windows store apps without having to use the windows store app

Tags: windows, windows-store, app

We have windows update blocked from reaching out to the internet, since we use wsus to update windows. However, this is also blocking the windows store from downloading updates to microsoft apps.

I have tried using winget... but it too is not able to get the msstore apps files because of the gpo stopping windows update from reaching out to the internet.

I read about adguard website and tested it on an off network machine, however, would prefer a more security conscious way than using that site.

Has anyone found any other way?

Comment: You understand that the adguard website redirects you to a package directly from Microsoft, right? You will need at least a single machine connected to the internet to get the package.  Doesn't sound like you have an infrastructure that supports that requirement. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1721755/is-there-a-way-to-install-microsoft-store-exclusive-apps-without-store) should still work. If your IT Administrators have gone to the effort of blocking WIndows Update, then it sounds like, your IT Administrators should be handle updating the UWP applications installed on your system.

Comment: "*...would prefer a more security conscious way than using that site*". TBH what's not security conscious given that the site only provides you direct download links from Microsoft themselves, you can see where you're downloading from.

Comment: @ramhound yeah i am one of the admins trying to figure out a good way of doing this within our policy xD

I understand both of what you are saying about adguard... however it is hosted in russia and given the tensions between the united states and russia currently, I just don't see it as a great idea to use it. I understand it grabs from microsoft, but that doesn't mean a payload cant be added to it before it actually gets to me.

Comment: @Karbashi, that's incorrect. It doesn't  just "grab it from Microsoft" it actually gives you a Microsoft lift for the download.

Comment: @Karbashi - The actual URL you download the package is **directly** from Microsoft. Winget is the only other method. "that doesn't mean a payload cant to be added to it before it gets to me. " - That is precisely what it means.  You will have to download the packages on a machine that can access the packages, otherwise, there isn't a method that exists if you block the actual source of the package.

Comment: Yeah sorry i said it incorrectly, I have no guarantee that the link they give me will always be correct.

I have been trying to figure out how they grab it for their site, I have dug around the network traffic a little for msstore and found this url to see if i can figure out how adguard gets the urls

https://apps.microsoft.com/store/api

but I am not sure if it offers that functionality, I use something similar for scraping dell drivers... But I cannot find anything about documentation in regards to using it to grab msstore apps.